# Windows: Limiting internet connection to one application

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

Recently, while gaming, I've discovered by accident that I get a much better ping over a mobile 4G connection. While using a wired connection my ping is around 40-70 ms, wireless 60-100 ms and over 4G I get around 25-40 ms. The 4G connection also seems a lot more stable.

As we all know 4G connections can get expensive for daily usage on a PC. Is there any way I can set up 2 games to connect over the 4G adapter, when available? But all other applications should keep using the wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix(more of a workaround) for this that I can think of is potentially using [routing rules](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/) for the game servers - any connections to those servers will be routed specifically through the 4G gateway. By standard configuration, the other programs should use wired anyway. If not, I believe there are priority rules you can look at.

I should also point out that this is an EXTREMELY hacky way of doing it that may not even work - however, i haven't managed to force a process onto a certain NIC in the past, so I have no native ideas that work apart from maybe this one.

I can also recommend you actually look at your router settings and discover why your ping is so large for your wired connection. This essentially indicates it takes long for the ping to go and return to your computer from the target server. Its possible you have a very low bandwidth and its being saturated - try ping tests when no one else is using the internet connection, and if it gets better, then it means your allocated bandwidth by your ISP is too low - at least you can pester them to increase it :)

If the ping doesn't change, it just means your device is too far from the server which introduces the constant latency. (this is all assuming you are also connected directly to your router - things like powerline adapters and ethernet repeaters can all introduce some sort of latency)

Comment: The reason why my ping is rather high is that I live in a big city. I recently moved here, although it is the same ISP as when I lived in a less dense area and they deliver quite good speeds.  I will take a look at the routing rules.